# Disable painting on a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paint, jcomponent

I'm trying to completely disable all painting and refreshing on a portion of a JFrame. I got the desired effect on the entire JFrame by simply overriding `public void paint(Graphics)` like so:

```
import javax.swing.*;

class Test extends JFrame {

  Test () {
    setBounds(20,20, 100,100);
    setVisible(true);
    }

  //This disables all painting and refreshing ON A JFRAME.
  //Just doing this on a JPanel doesn't work.
  public void paint (Graphics g) {}

  public static void main (String[] args)
    { new Test(); }

  }
```

I want this same effect, but only on a particular region of the JFrame. I want to be able to add GUI components like normal to the rest of the frame.  I've tried disabling double buffering (using JPanel's constructor) and overriding the following methods (extending both JPanel and JComponent) like so:

```
public class DontRefresh extends JComponent/JPanel {
  public void paint (Graphics g) {}
  public void paintComponent (Graphics g) {}
  public void repaint () {}
  public void update (Graphics g) {}
  public void updateUI () {}
  }
```

and i also tried disabling refresh via:

```
DontRefresh component = new DontRefresh();
RepaintManager.currentManager(component).markCompletelyClean(component);
```

but nothing worked.

Comment: Your desired effect is not really precise. Could you tell us what should be seen in your non-paintable JPanel: is it transparency or should it be a fixed color? in the first case just set setOpaque to false, in the latter simply paint the color you want on the background.

Comment: *"I'm trying to completely disable all painting and refreshing on a portion of a JFrame."*  You're trying to intentionally break the GUI?  What feature does that provide?

Answer (score 5):

Well, without knowing exactly what you're doing I would recommend you have a "filler panel" (just a JPanel you don't do anything with) in the space you don't want anything to appear and then have other panels for everything else.

So say you have a JFrame. If you wanted the top right corner to never display anything, you could fill the JFrame with 4 JPanels, one in each corner (or 3 with one on the left, one in the top right corner and one in the bottom right corner). Then put all you swing components in the other panels. I don't know if this will accomplish your purpose, but I'm not totally certain what you're purpose is, so that's the best I can do :) I hope it helps!

Comment: I don't know what he's doing either, but I'll up-vote you for the effort!